# PHP & MySql check if table is empty

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm a bit of a noob- and I'm having a hard time...

I need a bit of of code that searches a db table to find the row that matches the $id variable. There's a field in that table 'description' that I need to grab. If it's null, I need to show one message, if not another. Here's the code I have (I know I need to add the mysqli escape string, just doing this real quick from memory):

```
$query = "SELECT description FROM posts WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ;

if(!$row){
echo "<p>'No description'</p>";
} else {
echo '<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Oh - here's what it's doing. It returns the description either way, regardless of data in db.

Comment: You're missing some semicolons and whatnot as well ;p

Comment: if ( $row <= 0 ) echo 'empty'; else echo $row['description']; It works so well to me. Or try to use mysql_num_row() function to control your results.

Comment: Question title is not correct, it's not about only checking for emptyness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` will fetch a row regardless of if the columns in that row are null. You want to be checking if `$row['description']` is set instead of if `$row` is set:

```
$query = "SELECT description FROM posts WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(isset($row['description'])) {
    echo "<p>No description</p>";
} else {
    echo '<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>';
}
```

**EDIT:** Or, as an alternative, you can *not fetch rows from the database where description is NULL:*

```
$query = "SELECT description FROM posts WHERE id = $id AND description IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(! $row) {
    echo "<p>No description</p>";
} else {
    echo '<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>';
}
```

**Now** you'd check to see if you were able to grab a row or not.

Comment: Don't forget to `LIMIT 1` the query too, don't want to go through the whole table once it finds the row with the id, assuming that id is unique of course.

Comment: If `id` is marked as `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` index, MySQL will now by itself not to scan entire table once the only row has been found.

Comment: @user517593, you can mark an answer the correct one by using the check mark icon next to it.

Answer (score 2):

The `!$row` will only occur if no record is found. If the field description is really `null`, you have to check it this way:

```
if(is_null($row['description'])){
```

but I recommend you to check if the value is empty (or 0 or null):

```
if(empty($row['description'])){
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE `description` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: But it will give me a count either way. I tried a mysqli_num_rows and doing a statement like "if == 0, do this... if == 1, do this" but it's not checking what's in the field, just that there is one so each one came back a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you can do the check from within your query using `COALESCE`:

```
$query = "SELECT COALESCE(description, 'No description') FROM posts WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ;
echo $row['description'];
```

This way, when there is a value for the `description` field, it will be shown otherwise `No description` will be output. So that way, you can do away with the `if` condition of PHP.

Comment: plus one for concise code. although, if "description is null" has more consequences than changing the output, then this is bad.

Comment: @dav: `COALESCE` will stop NULLs poping in with user friendly message, it is essentially the same as what OP was doing with PHP :)

Comment: exactly. so as long as that is the only consequence, this is fine. if there are other consequences, then it is **not** fine. let's say something needs to be set in the session, or whatever, when a description does or doesn't exist. then it's not possible to find out if this extra behavior should be executed in the application. or there's a security risk where setting your description to "No description" would cause a behavior that's not in line with the original concept of the application.