# How to check if database is empty?

Tags: php

How do i check if database is empty?

I have some code her that shows the database, but i cant find out how to check if its empty and post out a echo if it is.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["brugernavn"])) {
    echo '<center><div class="euxaklassen">OVERSIGT OVER EUX A KLASSEN</div>
          <div class="hr"><hr></div>';
    $show = mysqli_query ($con,"select id,opgave,elev from karakter LIMIT 3")or die("Fejl!");   
    
    while(list($id,$opgave,$elev)=
    mysqli_fetch_array($show))
    {
        echo '<div class="opgave"><a href="euxaid.php?id='.$id.'&action=delete">'.$opgave.' ('.$elev.') </div><div class="hr"><hr></div></a></a>';
        
    } }
```

?>

Comment: Database or just that table?

Comment: Couple of issues:
What do you mean by database empty? do you mean the database has no tables or that a specific table has no rows?
Also not related to your question but noticed it in your code, on the 2 echo statements they both contain an opening hr tag `<hr>` but neither of them close the tag and the second echo contains an extra `</a>` tag

Comment: Search before asking any question, check this [PHP & MySql check if table is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854148/php-mysql-check-if-table-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

You can query `table schema` like this:

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name';
```

This will return count of rows from all tables in given database.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean check data in table, use mysql_num_rows to count number of rows

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($show)== 0){
   echo "Data is empty";
}else{
   // do something if not empty
}
```

Comment: something error or what ? you need explain more information

Comment: If i add the code you enter, it wont output the messeage that it is empty, but if is not empty it WILL output that it is not empty

Comment: try this `if(mysqli_num_rows($show)== 0)`

Comment: `$show = mysqli_query ($con,"select id,opgave,elev from karakter LIMIT 3")or die("Fejl!"); 
while(list($id,$opgave,$elev)=
mysqli_fetch_array($show))
if (mysqli_num_rows($show)==0) 
{
echo "tom";
}else
{
echo '<div class="opgave"><a href="euxaid.php?id='.$id.'&action=delete">'.$opgave.' ('.$elev.') </div><div class="hr"><hr></div></a></a>';
} 
} `

Still wont work... Still shows the fields when not empty but wont echo if its empty

Comment: can you check this result if data from table is empty or not `$count= mysqli_num_rows($show);` and `echo $count;`

Comment: It shows the number 4 which is the same inside the database

Comment: what the result if the data inside `karakter` is empty ?

Comment: Undefined variable: count in